# ¿Como hago para que se la cerradura no se pueda abrir nunca mas? Java POO

Tags: java, poo

> Implementa la clase Cerradura. Luego verifica:
>
> a. Que cuando ingresas una clave correcta se abra
>
> b. Que cuando ingresas una clave incorrecta no se abra
>
> c. Que si ingresas de forma incorrecta la clave la cantidad máxima de
>   intentos, ya no puedas abrir la cerradura

El problema es que no se que hacer para que el punto c) me funcione , no puedo usar for en este ejercicio , solo if .Yo puse la variable cantidadDeFallosConsecutivosQueLaBloquean como contador , asi se acumula dentro del metodo abrir , y luego en el metodo fueBloqueado puse un if y si esa variable es igual a 5 no se abre mas , pero no resulta.

```
public class Cerradura {

//Atributos
private int claveDeApertura = 1234;
private int cantidadDeFallosConsecutivosQueLaBloquean;
private boolean estado = false;

//Constructor
public Cerradura (int claveDeApertura ) {
    this.claveDeApertura = claveDeApertura;
    this.cantidadDeFallosConsecutivosQueLaBloquean = cantidadDeFallosConsecutivosQueLaBloquean;

}

//Metodos
public boolean abrir(int clave) {

    cantidadDeFallosConsecutivosQueLaBloquean++;

    if(claveDeApertura == clave) {

        estado=true;

        System.out.println("Se abre la cerradura.");
    }else {
        System.out.println("No se puede abrir la cerradura , contraseña incorrecta.");

    }
    return estado ;
}

public void cerrar () {

System.out.println("Cerradura cerrada.");
}

public boolean fueBloqueda() {

    if(cantidadDeFallosConsecutivosQueLaBloquean ==5) {




        System.out.println("La cerradura fue bloqueada , ha utilizado la cantida maxima de intentos.");
    }

    return estado;
}
}

---------------------------
public class PruebaCerradura {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cerradura c1 = new Cerradura(1234);
        c1.abrir(1210);
        c1.cerrar();
        c1.abrir(1548);
        c1.abrir(1548);
        c1.abrir(1548);
        c1.abrir(1548);
        c1.abrir(1548);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1)En el constructor, la variable cantidadDeFallosConsecutivosQueLaBloquean debes iniciarla en 0 (e intentar darle un nombre mas corto jajajaja).

2)El condicional que evalua si esa variable llego al maximo, se debe dar en el metodo que intenta abrir la cerradura, que dicho sea de paso deberia ser un void, y no devolver un boolean. Es decir, esto:

```
public void abrir(int clave){
       if(cantidadDeFallosConsecutivosQueLaBloquean<5){//primero se verifica que el numero de intentos no se haya excedido
               if(clave==claveDeApertura){//Si no se excedio, se evalua si la clave es correcta
                 System.out.println("Contraseña correcta, cerradura desbloqueada");
                }else{
                  System.out.println("Contraseña incorrecta, intente nuevamente");
                 }
       }else{
           System.out.println("Se ha alcanzado el numero maximo de intentos, cerradura bloqueada permanentemente");
         }
       cantidadDeFallosConsecutivosQueLaBloquean++; //Finalmente, aumentamos la variable que cuenta los intentos
```

Comment: Un par de cosas, si añades 1 cada vez que intentas abrir solo vas a tener 5 intentos aciertes o falles, solo se debería incrementar cuando se falle y se debería iniciar a 0 cuando se acierte para reiniciar el contador. (Aunque eso tampoco lo ha puesto el usuario que ha hecho la pregunta)

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar una ***propiedad estática de tipo entero*** en la clase *Cerradura*. ***Inicializala a 0 y suma uno cada intento fallido*** a esta propiedad. **Comprueba su valor antes de permitir abrirse a la cerradura**, una vez validada la clave. Alcanzado el número máximo debe impedir que se abra.